# Bracket extending on two lines

Tags: amsmath, texshop

I need to write something like this in latex:

[image]

I can use `\Big\{` or `\bigg\{`, but the problem is that all I write next goes on a single line. I need to embed the bracket into two lines, how to do that in latex?

Comment: Please add your MWE (your current code) to the post, it will help us to start working on it.

Comment: The common solution to this looks something like this: `\left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} ... \end{array} \right.` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `mathtools`, which is an extended `amsmath` and also `\left...\right`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  C_2 = 
    \begin{cases}
      0.45 \times \dfrac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+0.09}
        \times \sin \alpha
    & \text{if $\gamma \geq 0$}
    \\[4pt]
      0.45 \times \dfrac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+0.09}
        \times \left(\sin \alpha - \left(\dfrac{2 \beta}{\pi}\right)^3\right)
      & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `cases` just requires `amsmath`; it's `dcases` that requires `mathtools`; within `dcases` `\dfrac` can be `\frac` and the vertical spacing is improved.

Comment: It ia _always_ a good idea to load `mathtools` instead of `amsmath` ...

Comment: And the starred versions suppose the second part is text, so you don't have to type \text a number of times.